# Hello Everyone, I am trying to cross compile bintuils on ubuntu for a custom OS, when i am compiling i get the error multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: makefile, operating-system, gnu-make, osdev, binutils

here is the error

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
config.status: executing default commands
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/master/src/build-binutils-airos/ld'
Makefile:1805: *** multiple target patterns. Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/master/src/build-binutils-airos/ld'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:7194: all-ld] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/master/src/build-binutils-airos'
make: *** [Makefile:852: all] Error 2
root@WS1:/home/master/src/build-binutils-airos#
```

I have done the changed specified in this page only changed the myos to airos
https://wiki.osdev.org/OS_Specific_Toolchain

I am following this page to compile
https://wiki.osdev.org/Hosted_GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: The message `Makefile:1805: ...` means that error is in the file `Makefile` at line 1805.  What is there (and a few lines before/after--_not_ the entire file)?  Usually this error means there are extraneous `:` characters in filenames etc: make sure that none of your paths/directories contain `:` characters, which are special to make.

Answer (score 0):

please check your Makefile line1805, there maybe some write errors. like a ":".